# Pass value from class to another class

Tags: apex, class, aura, parameters

I have a class which receives a value from a lightning component how do I pass this value to another class. I get the error:

> incorrect signature

Return Class

```
public class PassDoelgroep {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static  string Doelgroep(String Doelgroep) {
        return Doelgroep;
    }
}
```

Value to Class

```
public class picklistController {   
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Opleiding__c> findAll() {  
    String doelgroep =  PassDoelgroep.Doelgroep();   
   return [SELECT id, name, Doelgroep__c   
           FROM Opleiding__c 
           WHERE Actief__c=true
           AND Doelgroep__c = :Doelgroep    
           LIMIT 50];   
    }
}
```

Comment: So, you're calling two different methods, in two different controllers, presumably from two different components?

Comment: @sfdcfox I have one controller with two methods but these methods are called by different lightning components. What I want to achieve is that when the first return Doelgroep happens the value Doelgroep is accessible by the other methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code in picklistController ,

```
   String doelgroep =  PassDoelgroep.Doelgroep('test'); //Pass your string.
```

I think you are missing parameter for Doelgroep. that why you are getting "incorrect signature" error

//According to your requirement

write these two methods(Doelgroep,findAll) inside one 
   controller.Using action.setparams to  pass your String 
     Doelgroep value to findAll() method

```
   public static List<Opleiding__c> findAll(string Doelgroep) {
```

Comment: If it ressolves your query.Please mark it as best answer and close it off.Thanks

Comment: Dit you get my question. My Lightning component passes 'test" into class PassDoelgroep. I want to get the return from Doelgroep into  public class picklistController. I want to get the return from Doelgroep into several other classes. Sonething like String doelgroep = get return Doelgroep

Comment: I had given the example.You have to pass paremeter !!!! for Doelgroep that should be string type.

Comment: My Lightning component passes the parameter already, this part works. Now I wat to get this parameter to the class picklistcontroller into the method FindAll.

Comment: uff man..what you posted before..see write these two  methods  in  (Doelgroep,findAll) method inside on controller..using action.setparams in java script side  pass your String Doelgroep value to findAll() method...